# How delete all data from the '.txt' file using python 2?

Tags: python

I want to delete all data from my **data.txt** file:

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('data.txt', 'w'): pass
```

This will delete the contents of `'data.txt'`, leaving an empty file. (This works in Python3 too).

Answer (score 1):

Just do: `open(file,'w').close()`

Answer (score 0):

`open(file, 'w')` can work for you. Don't forget to close the file or use a `with`.